# Sempre incluir registros da outra tabela se o valor do campo relacionado não for NULL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou fazendo uma query de consulta, com base em uma tabela.

Nessa tabela (tableA) eu trago vários registros de outras tabelas, com alguns códigos mas um em especial está me dando certa dor de cabeça.

Existe um registro na tableA que pode ser NULL e nesse caso a query não precisa buscar o nome referente a esse registro (é um código), tentei com CASE no WHERE e no SELECT e a query retornou diversas linhas repetidas, adicionei GROUP BY, mas não ajudou muito.

Atualmente a query está assim.

```
SELECT
       tableA.numero,
       tableA.valor,
       tableA.codigo,
       tableB.nome,
       tableC.nome,
       tableD.nome = CASE
               WHEN tableA.tabled IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
               ELSE tableD.nome
           END,
       tableE.nome
    FROM tableA,
         tableB,
         tableC,
         tableD,
         tableE
    WHERE tableA.data = now()
      AND tableA.ativo = '1'
      AND tableA.tableb = tableB.codigo
      AND tableA.tablec = tableC.codigo
      AND CASE
              WHEN tableA.tabled IS NOT NULL THEN tableA.tabled = tableD.codigo
              ELSE 1 = 1
          END
      AND tableA.tabled = tabled.codigo
```

Comment: Uma boa prática de programação é não realizar `JOIN` direto na cláusula `FROM`, e sim utilizando explicitamente a cláusula `JOIN` (`SELECT ... FROM TabelaA ta JOIN TabelaB tb ON ta.Id = tb.Id JOIN ...`). Qual resultado esta obtendo? Sua query não pode retornar valor neste campo, ou não irá existir uma tupla referenciada quando `tableA.tabled` é `NULL`?

Comment: Ela fiz um gato com `GROUP BY` e ela retorna uma linha para cada registro de tableD.

Comment: Continuo sem entender nada. Eu arriscaria que o `LEFT JOIN`, tal qual sugerido pelo Cigano, é a solução que procura. Porém não consegui entender ao certo seu problema para poder ajudar mais.

Comment: Sem problemas, a solução dele funcionou. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso que voê quer é um [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](http://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Pr%C3%A1tico/DML/Consultas_Join#LEFT_OUTER_JOIN). Não é preciso o `CASE` justamente porque o `LEFT OUTER JOIN` traz o registro mesmo se a associação não existir.

```
SELECT
   tableA.numero,
   tableA.valor,
   tableA.codigo,
   tableB.nome,
   tableC.nome,
   tableD.nome,
   tableE.nome
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.tableb = tableB.codigo
INNER JOIN tableC ON tableA.tablec = tableC.codigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableD ON tableA.tabled = tableD.codigo
INNER JOIN tableE ON tableA.tablee = tableE.codigo
WHERE tableA.data = now()
  AND tableA.ativo = '1'
```